# Exporting rows to a text file from dataGridView in C# only exports first row

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I want to export rows to a text file. Not all rows, but only rows that are checked in `dataGridView` when I click on the export button. My problem is my program exports only the first row entered, and only one time. When I check more than row in a condition of selected I have put a checkbox in cells of index 0. This is what my export button contains:

```
private void buttonExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter str = new System.IO.StreamWriter("fichier.txt");
            dataa= dataset.Tables["Rech"];
            str.WriteLine("NumRep  " + " Description   " + " DateRep  " + "  cout  " + " Matricule    " + " CodeRep   " + " CodeTypeRep   ");
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
            {


                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected == true) // checkbox checked
                {


                    str.WriteLine(dataa.Rows[i][0] + "    " + dataa.Rows[i][1] + "    "  +dataa.Rows[i][2]
                      + " " +dataa.Rows[i][3] + "    " + dataa.Rows[i][4] + dataa.Rows[i][5] + " " + dataa.Rows[i][6]);
                }
            }
            str.Close();
        }
```

I don't know where the problem is with my logic.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this:

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected == true) // checkbox checked
{
...
}
```

to this:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chkCell = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
if (chkCell.Value.Equals(chkCell.TrueValue)) // checkbox checked
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRow row  DataGridView1.Row[i]
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
if (Convert.ToBoolean(chk.Value) == true)
```

You can try above to get what you needed out of DataGridView.  It worked for me.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my condition to this :

```
if ((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == true)
```

and it worked for me.

thanks to all !!